# How to always set the same charset?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have an application developed in Delph7. (not Unicode) 
Unable to change to the new Delphi and do not want to use Tn .. or other components.

Is it possible to make changes in Graphics.pas or other Unite that
in each control Charset is EASTEUROPE_CHARSET or SYMBOL_CHARSET.

So when the text: 
-loaded from the file 
-saved the file 
-pasted from clipboard 
-copied to clipboard 
-typed on keyboard 
etc.

Need ALWAYS change in EASTEUROPE_CHARSET except when is SYMBOL_CHARSET.

Simply put, Font.Charset can only be 
EASTEUROPE_CHARSET or SYMBOL_CHARSET

Comment: You've decided on a solution. It doesn't sound like a good one but you've made it clear that you don't want to entertain any other approach. So what's stopping you implementing your solution?

Comment: All of my clients need EASTEUROPE_CHARSET. 
Some of the clients have the wrong setting in Win. (language nonunicode programs) 

That's why I want you to always EASTEUROPE_CHARSET regardless of the settings in Win (an exception is SYMBOL_CHARSET)

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007703/programmatically-change-the-default-code-page-in-windows-xp-from-delphi

Comment: @user - Playing with font charsets won't help.